# How to write this long square-root equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
√{[√(6x-9)+√(4x-4)+√(2x-1)][√(6x-9)+√(4x-4)-√(2x-1)][√(4x-4)+√(2x-1)-√(6x-9)][√(6x-9)+√(2x-1)-√(4x-4)]}={(x-3)×√(6x-9)}+{(x-2)×√(4x-4)}+{(x-1)×√(2x-1)}
```

It is something like this. When I use latex this is what I get

```
\begin{equation}
\small
\sqrt{ (\sqrt{6x-9} + \sqrt{4x-4} + \sqrt{2x-1})(\sqrt{6x-9} + \sqrt{4x-4} - \sqrt{2x-1})(\sqrt{4x-4} + \sqrt{2x-1} - \sqrt{6x-9})(\sqrt{6x-9} + \sqrt{2x-1} - \sqrt{4x-4})}=(x-3)\sqrt{6x-9}+(x-2)\sqrt{4x-4}+(x-1)×\sqrt{2x-1}
\end{equation}
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: `\small` is text-mode command; hence, it shouldn't be use in math mode. To render the entire `equation` environment at a smaller fontsize, one would have to write `\begingroup\small \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}\endgroup`.

Comment: @Mico thank you very much

Comment: This is my first time post in here, I dun know that I can't write any equation. Thanks for help editing

Comment: If you want to reproduce the confusing version, use \surd instead of \sqrt.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that splits the full equation across three lines, with the help of a `multline` environment. The long square-root expression to the left of the `=` symbol is typeset using `(...)^{1/2}` notation in order to allow a line break. And, of course, `\sqrt{...}` constructs replace the `√{...}` inputs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\smash[b]{\Bigl\{}
      \bigl[\sqrt{6x-9}+\sqrt{4x-4}+\sqrt{2x-1}\,\bigr]
      \bigl[\sqrt{6x-9}+\sqrt{4x-4}-\sqrt{2x-1}\,\bigr]\\
\times\bigl[\sqrt{4x-4}+\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{6x-9}\,\bigr]
      \bigl[\sqrt{6x-9}+\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{4x-4}\,\bigr]
\smash[t]{\Bigr\}^{1/2}} \\
=(x-3)\sqrt{6x-9}+(x-2)\sqrt{4x-4}+(x-1)\sqrt{2x-1}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I would prefer a style which rephrases this expression as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)} = a(x-3) + b(x-2) + c(x-1)
\end{equation}
where $a = \sqrt{6x - 9}$, $b = \sqrt{4x-4}$, and $c = \sqrt{2x-1}$. 
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

If you prefer to use the expanded out form with `\sqrt{...}` instead of `{...}^{1/2}`, here is a variation of @Mico's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\sqrt{\begin{lgathered}
      \bigl[\sqrt{6x-9}+\sqrt{4x-4}+\sqrt{2x-1}\,\bigr]
      \bigl[\sqrt{6x-9}+\sqrt{4x-4}-\sqrt{2x-1}\,\bigr]\\
\times\bigl[\sqrt{4x-4}+\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{6x-9}\,\bigr]
      \bigl[\sqrt{6x-9}+\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{4x-4}\,\bigr]
    \end{lgathered}}
    \\
=(x-3)\sqrt{6x-9}+(x-2)\sqrt{4x-4}+(x-1)\sqrt{2x-1}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Yeah haha, it is Heron formula for the left hand and for the right hand it is the sum area in the triangle. I put original equation in Wolfram Alpha ( of course, I dun want to solve this disturbing looking equation ) and afterward I need to write it properly but I can't...hahahha. Maybe using ur simplify form is better

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but how to use this code? I copy this and put in my solution but it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get a compilation error or do you get an output which looks visually different. Are you trying the example that I provided in my answer, or copy pasting it in a bigger document? Note that the second example requires the `mathtools` package.

Comment: I copy the second one from \documentclass...to \end{document} and paste it

Comment: And... do you get a compilation error (if so, please post it) or does it render differently.

Comment: I'm sorry, my knowledge for Latex is still limited. Could you tell me how I could copy this latex and use it? It seem that straight forward copy this is not working. Is there any step I miss?

Comment: I copy this code and use it but it gives me this code back, not the equation

Comment: As I have asked multiple times, can you explain what you mean by 'it is not working'. Do you get a compile error? If so, what is the error message.

Comment: There isn't any error message it just give me the code where I'm copying

Comment: I have no clue how you could possibly get the latex code in the output PDF in the above example. Perhaps, you can create another question which explains the output you are seeing and someone else might be able to help.

Comment: It may be better to ask a separate question on the forum.